# C# Active Directory - Incorrect Username and Password but details are actually correct

Tags: c#, active-directory

Issue with Active Directory & C#. I'm getting an intermittent error stating that "The user name or password is incorrect.". However, I know the login details are correct as it works Locally in VS. It seemingly doesn't on the web server everytime.

**Error:**

```
The user name or password is incorrect.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

My code for storing the connection to the LDAP, bits hidden for security reasons:

```
    public static DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntryWithGc()
    {
        var de = new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT");
        de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        de.Username = "USERNAME";
        de.Password = "PASSWORD";
        return de;
    }
```

As mentioned, works Locally and is intermittent. Anyone any experience of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but is there more than one domain in your AD forest? And are you including the domain name in `"USERNAME"` (i.e. `"DOMAIN\USERNAME"`)?

Using `GC://` without specifying a server name can connect to a server from any of the domains in your forest. If you did not specify the domain name in your username, then it will assume the username is from the server's domain, which may not be the case.

If I'm correct in this, then you can solve the issue by including the domain name with the username:

```
de.Username = "DOMAIN\USERNAME";
```

Comment: @WHoward Because you're using `GC://`, you aren't actually specifying a domain. You're specifying a forest. So `"GC://dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT"` tells it that you want to connect to a Global Catalog in the AD forest that the `text.text.text` domain belongs to. It can connect to any Global Catalog server in the forest, which may or may not belong to the `text.text.text` domain.

Comment: You can force it to use a GC from a specific domain by specifying a server name (or just the DNS name of the domain, in which case it will use any GC from the domain), like this: `"GC://text.text.text/dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT,dc=TEXT"` But there isn't really any need to do that. Just let it pick a GC by itself and specify the domain of the user account.

Comment: makes sense appreciated