# PowerShell error: Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect. "

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server

There is a Windows Server VM in my department that hosts some of our Web Applications. We want one of this Web Applications to get, automatically, the user department based on his NT-USER. To do so, we imagine the following path:

1. User enters in the Website. His NT-User is automatically taken
   by IIS Whindows Authentication;
2. We Powershell (using an Active
   Directory API) using the NT-User as a parameter;
3. We finally get
   the user name and department.

This API works fine in my personal computer, but not in the Server. I am executing a Powershell script like this:

```
$helpstring = find-user 'fie7ca' | select displayname, name, st, l, distinguishedname
$helpstring;
```

In my personal computer:

It works fine.

But then (in the Server), I receive the following error:

```
Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect.
"
At C:\Users\RBAdmin_App2\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BC-Tools\User-Functions.psm1:496 char:11
+           $user = $searcher.FindOne()
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryServicesCOMException
```

I am imagine that I need a Active Directory feature, use LDAP or something that I do not know.

Comment: Is it the same user you're searching for?

Comment: When running from the server are you logged in as a domain user?

Comment: `<NT-User>`, is a local user. If you use the same name for the domain/server user, you probably need to do something like `<ServerName>\<NT-User>` `<DomainName>\<NT-User>` or `.\<NT-User>` for the remote user name.

Comment: What is `Find-User`?

Comment: You can't expect us to find what's wrong with some function you use from some module unless you show it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251736/c-sharp-active-directory-incorrect-username-and-password-but-details-are-actua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was regarding the company proxy.